# Why is the iphone 6s battery inferior to the 7?

Tags: iphone, battery

https://www.cnet.com/reviews/apple-iphone-6s-review/

CNET 2018 indicates the 6s has:

> Inferior battery life, camera performance and processor speed compared
>   to newer iPhones.

What exactly is the battery life inferior? Possible reasons comprise:

- fewer mA-hours battery?
- CPU voltage swing greater? (greater power consumption?
- Display power efficiency?

Comment: When you say inferior are you doing a thought experiment where you remove the batteries from both devices and compare them in isolation or are you interested in how each device performs under some specific benchmark or test? I'm not voting to close as too broad / opinionated, but this might need an edit so we can understand what you're trying to accomplish. The "well duh" answer would be Apple intentionally designed the newer batter to be better since they had another year of experience and development to improve things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely convinced the author of the article you referenced did his homework! I've heard that battery improvements from iPhone 6 to iPhone 7 have been incremental. That jibes with battery technology progress in general (i.e. slow progress), and a quick search found [this article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2016/11/03/iphone-7-vs-iphone-6-whats-the-difference/) that seems to back up the "limited improvement" opinion:

> "... the battery capacity has changed little (iPhone 6 - 1810mAh, iPhone 7 - 1960mAh) and you’ll still struggle to get a full day out of it...

Those figures are repeated in [this article - a compilation of battery capacities for all iPhone models from 2007 to 2017.](https://docrazytricks.com/apple-iphone-battery-capacity-in-mah/)  One interesting thing to note from the table is that "size matters" - for batteries at least. Notice that the jumbo [**phablets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phablet) have significantly more battery capacity, but that's down to the batteries being larger. And of course a **phablet** will demand more power than a 'normal' phone due to the larger display.

For all these reasons, I'd tend to discount the claim that battery life is "inferior" for the 6S. I'm not saying that there's no improvement; I'm saying that the improvements are "evolutionary" instead of "revolutionary". "Inferior" suggests poor quality and/or significant differences, and the data simply do not bear that out. I think Apple will do what they have to do to remain competitive; that includes battery technology.

Comment: Get a « full day » out of iPhone 6s plus - but that dirs depend on use... if all you do is make a couple of calls, a dozen texts and a few photos with 5 mins of video... then fine. If you expect it to play video for 24hours without pause...

Comment: @SolarMike: Agreed. I don't believe that metrics like « full day » are meaningful by themselves. I suppose they do help "normalize" mAH ratings though... By that I only mean that it's also misleading to say, "That phablet has twice as many mAH as an iPhone, so it will last twice as long as my iPhone". Hope that's not controversial?

Comment: sorry, not pointing at you, just some of these "journalists" or "technical writers" spout so much c**p... You point out the bigger then the more power and that's about as good as you can get. plus 1 anyway.

Comment: @SolarMike: No - I didn't take it that way :)  And yes, there are tons of manure spread on the Internet each day by "ignorants". But battery specs confuse many people, so I'm willing to cut them a little slack. The best example of this was recently, when Apple throttled back the CPU to conserve power for older batteries, and there was widespread outrage! This was a brilliant solution - only the ignorant were outraged.